# How to change the url parameter value without affecting other parameter values

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

here i am trying to change one of the URL parameter value to either true or false based on button clicked.

say here i have an url

```
127.0.0.1:8080/cars/model?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=false&copyfalse=copy
```

i want to change of value `styleAttrSaved` to true or false based on the button i click without affecting anyother parameters, so once i change the value the url remains same with only that value changed.

here is what i have tried to do.

```
$('.submitForm').click(function(){
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    var cleanUrl = currentUrl.substring(0,currentUrl.indexOf('&')

    if($(this).attr('data-des') == true){
      var savedUrl = "&styleAttrSaved=true";
    } else {
      var savedUrl = "&styleAttrSaved=false";
    } 
        var finalUrl = cleanUrl+savedUrl;
    history.pushState(null,null,finalUrl);
});


<button class="submitForm" data-des="true">Submit true</button>
<button class="submitForm" data-des="false">Submit false</button>
```

Here in the code i am trying to replace the value by using sub string method.the problem i am facing here is that if i use this method, the whole URL gets changed

for example if i have url

```
127.0.0.1:8080/cars/model?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=false&copyfalse=copy
```

after i apply the above function, this the URL i get back

```
127.0.0.1:8080/cars/model?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=true
```

In the output url above you can see the value of `styleAttrSaved` has changed but the other parameter value `copyfalse=copy` is no longer available in the output of new url.I dont want to remove the other parameters from the URL, but i should change only value of one parameter in the URL, so that url remains same and just a value of `styleAttrSaved` gets changed to true like this

```
127.0.0.1:8080/cars/model?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=true&copyfalse=copy
```

How can i do this?

Comment: After `cleanUrl = currentUrl.substring(0,currentUrl.indexOf('&')`, `cleanUrl` ends with `?id=2003`. Then you append to it. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below common method:

```js
var url= '127.0.0.1:8080/cars/model?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=false&copyfalse=copy';

function changeParam(url,paramName,paramValue){
 var qind = url.indexOf('?');
 var params = url.substring(qind).split('&');
 var query = '';
 for(var i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
  var tokens = params[i].split('=');
  var name = tokens[0];
  var value = tokens[1];
  if(name == paramName) {
   value = paramValue;
  }
  if(query == '') {
   query = name + '=' + value;
  } else {
   query = query + '&' + name + '=' + value;
  }
 }
 return url.substring(0,qind) + query;
}

console.log(changeParam(url,'styleAttrSaved','true'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to easily alter the params for you. There is currently no support for it in IE and Safari mobile, but there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) for them

```js
var myURL = "127.0.0.1:8080/cars/model?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=false&copyfalse=copy";

let parsedURL = new URL(`http://${myURL}`);

parsedURL.searchParams.set("styleAttrSaved", true);

console.log(parsedURL.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you get first index of '&' you have to find second index of '&'

```
function getIndex(url, subStr, indexValue) {
   return url.split(subStr, indexValue).join(subStr).length;
}
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
var preUrl = currentUrl.substring(0,getIndex(currentUrl,"&",1));
var afterurl = currentUrl.substring(getIndex(currentUrl,"&",2),currentUrl.length);
if($(this).attr('data-des') == true){
      var savedUrl = "&styleAttrSaved=true";
    } else {
      var savedUrl = "&styleAttrSaved=false";
    } 
        var finalUrl = cleanUrl+savedUrl+afterurl;
    history.pushState(null,null,finalUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many times this was called / how long those URL strings can get, this should be workable. I haven't tested it so I don't know exactly *how* workable, but it was quick.

My basic idea here was to convert from uri string => object, where you can alter the values of the keys, and then back from object=>uri tail string (you obviously know the first part of the URL, or it is stored somewhere you can use).

This question is interesting to me, so I may come back in a bit with an edit for a way I found that I like more.

Keep in mind you could just run `String.replace` on the URL string you get, like so (if you are only ever going to change that portion, this might be way faster performance wise)

```
urlString.replace(/styleAttrSaved=(true|false)/, 'styleAttrSaved='+false
```

## More Complex Solution

```js
let url = '127.0.0.1:8080/cars/model?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=false&copyfalse=copy';
//Base URL String
function buildObjFromUrlParams(urlString){
  let matches = urlString.match(/\?(.*)/)[1], retObj={};
  //the matches only of anything on the URL after the ? character. Maybe a better Regex but this was the one I came up with based on a single sample
  retObj = matches.split('&').reduce(function(cum, cur){
    //split the matches by the & symbol, run them through the reduce function
    let [key, val] = cur.split('=');
    //Let the key equal the first index value, and val the second, from the current loop item split by the '=' character
    cum[key]=val;
    //set the key on the cumulative object equal to the value 
    // Note you may want to run a uridecode call on the value
    return cum;
    //return the object for use in next iterator
  }, retObj); //start off with an empty Object.
  
  return retObj;
  //You could realistically replace retObj with the matches.split... call up top, but I did this for personal readability
  
}

function buildUriTailFromObj(obj){
  let keys = Object.keys(obj), retStr = '';
  //declare the object's keys + the return string
  retStr = keys.map(function(key){
    //set the return string to the map of each key value 
    return key+'='+obj[key];
    //return the string made by combining the value of the string, the equal sign, and the object value.
    //NOTE may want ot add a uriencode call on the obj[key]
  }).join('&');// join the mapped string array by the & symbol
  
  return retStr;
  
}

let urlObj = buildObjFromUrlParams(url);
urlObj.styleAttrSaved=true;


buildUriTailFromObj(urlObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would rethink your design. You probably want to be able to change any of those when you want. Use Object oriented code that can set any of the get URL properties.

```js
function GetHandler(queryString){
  var searchStr = queryString || location.search;
  searchStr = searchStr.replace('?', '');
  var searchArray = searchStr.split('&');
  this.searchObj = {};
  for(var i=0,s,l=searchArray.length; i<l; i++){
    s = searchArray[i].split('='); this.searchObj[decodeURIComponent(s[0])] = decodeURIComponent(s[1]);
  }
  this.getPropVal = function(prop){
    return this.searchObj[prop];
  }
  this.setPropVal = function(prop, val){
    this.searchObj[prop] = val;
    return this;
  }
  this.removeProp = function(prop){
    var o = {};
    for(var i in this.searchObj){
      if(i !== prop)o[i] = this.searchObj[i];
    }
    this.searchObj = o;
    return this;
  }
  this.buildSearchStr = function(){
    var a = [], so = this.searchObj;
    for(var i in so){
      a.push(encodeURIComponent(i)+'='+encodeURIComponent(so[i]));
    }
    return a.join('&');
  }
}

var getHandler = new GetHandler('?id=2003&styleAttrSaved=false&copyfalse=copy');
console.log(getHandler.searchObj);
getHandler.setPropVal('styleAttrSaved', true);
getHandler.searchObj.id = 'Anything You Want Here';
console.log(getHandler.searchObj);
console.log(getHandler.buildSearchStr());
```

Just remove the `GetHandler` argument if you want it to be based on the current page get URL. Scroll down to the bottom after clicking the "Run code snippet" button to see the results you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your updated url is incomplete is because of how you're obtaining the original query string.

```
var cleanUrl = currentUrl.substring(0,currentUrl.indexOf('&'));
```

assigns all characters from the `href` *up until the first instance (zero index) of the `&` character*.

A solution that relies on a specific order of query parameters is perhaps a bit brittle.  Consider an alternative way to update this portion of the URL:

```
function buildParameterObject(query) {
    var parameters = {};
    var querySegments = query.slice(1).split("&");      
    querySegments.forEach(function(segment) {
        var prop = segment.split("=")[0];
        var val = segment.split("=")[1] || "";
        parameters[prop] = val;
    });
    return parameters;  
}

function buildQueryString(parameters) {
    var query = "";
    if (parameters === null || typeof parameters !== "object") {
        return query;
    }
    var keys = Object.keys(parameters);
    if (keys.length === 0) {
        return query;
    }
    var querySegments = [];
    Object.keys(parameters).forEach(function(parameter) {
        var segment = parameter;
        if (parameters[parameter].length > 0) {
            segment += "=" + parameters[parameter];
        }
        querySegments.push(segment);
    });
    query = "?" + querySegments.join("&");

    return query;
}

function buildUpdatedQueryStringWithParameter(parameterName, newValue) {
    var parameters = buildParameterObject(window.location.search);
    parameters[parameterName] = newValue;
    return buildQueryString(parameters);
}
```

In short, the preceding code does the following:

- Grab the query string
- Convert it into an object
- Modify the provided value or add the provided parameter and value as a new key/value pair
- Convert the object back into a query string
- Return the resulting string

So in your code, you could call `buildUpdatedQueryStringWithParameter`, passing your parameter name and the new value as arguments, and use the resulting string however you'd like (in conjunction with `history.pushState()` for example).